# group by having clause query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

Customer table : 
(Id,
FirstName,
LastName,
City,
Country,
Phone)

** List the number of customers in each country. Only include countries with more than 1 customers.
--> query will be as follows

```
 SELECT COUNT(Id), Country
    FROM Customer
    GROUP BY Country
    HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1

Results: 3 records
Count   Country
2   France
4   Germany
3   USA
```

Problem : 
I need to get names of these count ie. FirstName in the same query
EG : as below

```
Results: 3 records
    Count   Names             Country
    2       john,max          France
    4       abc,xyz,aab,cdf   Germany
    3       mmm,fmf,dm        USA
```

Is it possible?

Comment: group_concat FirstName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(id) as count,
       group_concat(first_name),
       country
from Customer
group by country
```

Group Concat function returns a string with concatenated non-NULL value from a group.